# Is there an other effective way to pass object as props through react components?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

its my App.js file

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./components/header/Header";

const App = () => {
  const data = {
    welcome: "Welcome to 30 Days Of React",
    title: "Getting Started React",
    subtitle: "JavaScript Library",
    author: {
      firstName: "Asabeneh",
      lastName: "Yetayeh",
    },
    date: new Date(), 
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="app">
       <Header data={data} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

and there is my Header.js component file

```
import React from "react";    

const Header = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <header>
      <div className="header-wrapper">
        <h1>{props.data.welcome}</h1>
        <h2>{props.data.title}</h2>
        <h3>{props.data.subtitle}</h3>
        <p>
          {props.data.author.firstName} {props.data.author.lastName}
        </p>
        </div>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

I've tried many other ways to pass an object as a props (like object destructuring) but it did not work, Is there a specific way to handle the communication among react components that i don't have to use the `props.data` so many times in the Header component

Comment: You have passed the data object under another data prop object so you can access props.data.welcome other then props.data.data.welcome.

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from "react";    

const Header = ({ data }) => {

const { welcome, title, subtitle, author } = data;
  
  return (
    <header>
      <div className="header-wrapper">
        <h1>{welcome}</h1>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <h3>{subtitle}</h3>
        <p>
          {author.firstName} {author.lastName}
        </p>
        </div>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

You can destructure the props like this

Comment: Thanks you, Im a newbie, BTW, Could you show me how can I pass function as props through components in reactjs ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done using use state hooks to pass data from the app component to the header component and show it. please check the demo in code sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-johnson-sny13?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Ya, thank you, Im just learning Reactjs right now and I have no experience with React hooks yet.

Comment: If this solution work for you so please upvote the answer to help others developers.